# Type discriminators

Tags: c#

Sometimes we need to map a .NET type to some custom nice looking text and resolve it back to the type latter. We could use it while implementing polymorphic behaviors in JSON API, or persisting/rehydrating class hierarchy.

Sometimes we need something more complex than 1:1 mapping. Let's say that we backed up part of our log database, so it's not so easy to update to comply with event discriminator modifications – we still need to understand old version of the terms, but use the new ones on output.

```
public abstract class Discriminator<T>
{
    public static Discriminator<T> Null = new NullDiscriminator<T>();

    public T Resolve(string discriminator, params object[] args) =>
        discriminator != null ?
            (T)Activator.CreateInstance(this[discriminator], args) :
            default(T);

    public string this[T obj] => this[obj?.GetType()];
    public abstract string this[Type type] { get; }
    public abstract Type this[string discriminator] { get; }
}
```

The class above defines two-directional mapping strategy between `Type` and some text discriminator. There are some implementations of it.

The one to do nothing:

```
class NullDiscriminator<T> : Discriminator<T>
{
    public override Type this[string discriminator] => null;
    public override string this[Type type] => null;
}
```

The one to transform type name by trimming namespace prefix and some optional suffix:

```
public class TrimmerDiscriminator<T> : Discriminator<T>
{
    public TrimmerDiscriminator(string prefix, string suffix = "")
    {
        Prefix = prefix;
        Suffix = suffix;
    }

    string Prefix { get; }
    string Suffix { get; }

    public override Type this[string discriminator]
    {
        get
        {
            if (discriminator == null)
                return null;

            return Type.GetType($"{Prefix}{discriminator}{Suffix}, {typeof(T).Assembly.FullName}");
        }
    }

    public override string this[Type type]
    {
        get
        {
            if (type == null)
                return null;

            var name = type.FullName;
            if (!name.StartsWith(Prefix))
                throw new FormatException("Non matching prefix.");
            if (!name.EndsWith(Suffix))
                throw new FormatException("Non matching suffix.");

            return name
                .Substring(0, name.Length - Suffix.Length)
                .Substring(Prefix.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

And a decorating one, to explicitly override mapping:

```
public static class OverrideDiscriminator
{
    public static Discriminator<T> Override<T>(this Discriminator<T> source, Type type, string discriminator) =>
        new OverrideDiscriminator<T>(source, type, discriminator);
}

public class OverrideDiscriminator<T> : Discriminator<T>
{
    public OverrideDiscriminator(Discriminator<T> source, Type type, string discriminator)
    {
        Source = source;
        Type = type;
        Discriminator = discriminator;
    }

    Discriminator<T> Source { get; }
    Type Type { get; } 
    string Discriminator { get; }

    public override Type this[string discriminator]
    {
        get
        {
            if (discriminator == Discriminator)
                return Type;

            return Source[discriminator];
        }
    }

    public override string this[Type type]
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == type)
                return Discriminator;

            return Source[type];
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say we have a demo class hierarchy:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public abstract class UserId
    {
        public static Discriminator<UserId> Discriminator =
             new TrimmerDiscriminator<UserId>("Demo.", "Id");

        protected UserId(int value)
        { Value = value; }

        public int Value { get; }
    }

    public class EmployeeId : UserId
    {
        Public EmployeeId(int value) : base(value) { }
    }

    public class AdminId : EmployeeId
    {
        public AdminId(int value) : base(value) { }
    }

    public class ClientId : UserId
    {
        public ClientId(int value) : base(value) { }
    }
}
```

Repository example:

```
class UserRepository
{
    int _value;
    string _role;

    public UserId UserId
    {
        set
        {
            _value = value.Value;
            _role = UserId.Discriminator[value];
        }
        get
        {
            return UserId.Discriminator
                .Resolve(_role, _value);
        }
    }
}
```

We could modify this code by locally overriding Discriminator before use:

```
class UserRepository
{
    static Discriminator<UserId> { get; } Discriminator = 
        UserId.Discriminator
            .Override(typeof(AdminId), "Administrator");

    int _value;
    string _role;

    public UserId UserId
    {
        set
        {
            _value = value.Value;
            _role = Discriminator[value];
        }
        get
        {
            return Discriminator
                .Resolve(_role, _value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now it rehydrates "Admin" and "Administrator", but writes "Administrator" only. We could start from `Discriminator.Null` instead of `UserId.Discriminator` and define mapping schema explicitly with multiple overrides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Discriminator<T> Null = new NullDiscriminator<T>();
```

Shouldn't this be a `const`, or `readonly`?

And why is it defined in `Discriminator`? It feels wrong if a parent class knows about its child class.

```
public TrimmerDiscriminator(string prefix, string suffix = "")
{
    Prefix = prefix;
    Suffix = suffix;
}

string Prefix { get; }
string Suffix { get; }
```

What's the purpose of using properties where fields would do?

```
if (!name.StartsWith(Prefix))
    throw new FormatException("Non matching prefix.");
if (!name.EndsWith(Suffix))
    throw new FormatException("Non matching suffix.");

return name
    .Substring(0, name.Length - Suffix.Length)
    .Substring(Prefix.Length);
```

That's probably not a practical problem, but for what it's worth it wouldn't work properly if prefix and suffix overlapped. I'd use a regex...

I would also include `name` and the expected (but not matching) prefix or suffix in your `FormatException` messages. The more contextual info in an exception message, the better. Otherwise if you don't catch it red-handed, you'd be wondering what exactly went wrong.

```
public UserId UserId
{
    set
    {
        _value = value.Value;
        _role = UserId.Discriminator[value];
    }
```

This is nitpicky now, but I would change the order of these assignments. Because If `Discriminator` throws an exception, the object will be left in inconsistent state. Again this is a consideration for easier debugging.

Comment: 1) Thanks, I forgot `readonly`.  2) Null pattern is usually treated as a special case. It is common to have Singleton as a member of base class and hide Null class itself from consumers by making it nested (not recomended for .NET) or just not public. 3) I could add validation to them latter without changing consuming code: here it should be no null values.

Comment: Ad. 2. I see, the point taken. Ad. 3. I don't understand - validation for getters? Aren't they only set in the constructor? Shouldn't these discriminators be immutable? (`readonly` would come in handy again :) )

Comment: I would do validation at the scope when it becomes possible, no latter than that - preferring property setter (narrow scope) over ctor (wide scope).  Yes, we need create private setters for that. To be pedantic I would allow `null>!null` transition in the property, but not `null>null`, `!null>null`, `!null>!null`. I mean that ctor should do validation when multiple values need to be orchestrated - see `self validating property` pattern. All this stuff  starting making sense when complexity grows during maintenance. But the first step is to use properties by default.

Comment: Interesting. Yes if that's where it's heading, this is the way to go I guess. Thanks for accepting my answer